# Check if file is saved in documents directory

Tags: ios, xcode

In my application, when I press on a button, I download a file from the internet, and then I read it. The only thing is that the file takes about five seconds to load, depending on the speed of the network, but since the file gets bigger and bigger, the time needed increases. If i save the file and after run the code to read it, the code runs but the file is not their, because it doen't wait the file to load. So I added an NSTimer of 6 seconds and it works. But if the file gets bigger I would need to change it. Is there a code to run the code to read the file, once the load is completed??

Thanks for the help

Since I use dropbox I can use this code (just found out):

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)localPath {

}
```

but it runs every time a file is downloaded, and I would like to run it for every 2 files loaded...

Comment: How do you download the file? Normally download API has some sort of callback when connection is finished...

Comment: What do you use to download the file? [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? Implement the delegate methods to be notified when the download is complete. Using a fixed duration timer like this is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: I download from dropbox, so I specify the file I want to download and the location I want it to be saved

Comment: Might it be - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedThumbnail:(NSString*)destPath {
  
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)localPath {
    NSLog(@"%@",localPath); //just to see the console log of what this method spits out
    NSString *documents = ***DOC_DIRECTORY_METHOD***;
    NSString *expectedFilePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDownloadedFile"];
    if ([localPath isEqualToString:expectedFilePath]) {
        //insert my read file method here
    }
}
```

I don't know what the variable localPath will output, either the full path or just the name of the file.  You might have to tweak this.

Good luck.